# Should I use Different packages or same to do this

Tags: java

I am working on a GUI based assignment (Sales Management Software) using Netbeans 7.1. It has 3 things -

1. the interface
2. the code
3. the database

Now I want to know that, should i use 3 different packages for it or only one? Also what about the frames, only one frame and more panels will be the good approach for it or more frames?

Comment: What would you consider the simplest to understand?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Package structure for a Java project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210567/package-structure-for-a-java-project)

Comment: Please limit it to 1 question per ..question. How to organize/make a GUI is an entirely different matter to how to arrange classes and packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split it up however it makes sense to you. You can always refactor if necessary, so if it's a small application you can lump everything together in the beginning and start separating it into modules later.

The number of frames is also up to you. Some GUIs use separate frames, but others might use a single frame and display different panels by using a CardLayout or TabbedPane.

Comment: *"Some GUIs use separate frames"*  Like Gimp (shudder).  There are very good reasons not to use separate frames.  Follow the link in my answer for details.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson  thanks a lot for providing me such a good information.

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson , you have talked about cardlayout there is there any way to understand them how to organize them? I have often tried to use them in many projects but when there are many button on the jframe they just look very bad and unorganized, like i have tried it on Sales management assignment too, as it has many panels (menus) so doing it on one frame looks very ugly.  Please provide me some good information on using them.

Comment: @codo: You might look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655843/230513).

Comment: It seems like you first need to understand [nested layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).  The idea would be to use a layout or combination of layouts that can contain related components and will assign extra space sensibly when resized, then put each of those groups into a panel that is added as one card of the card layout.  I could make more specific recommendations with a more specific spec. ..on a new question. ;)

Answer (score 1):

> ..what about the frames, only one frame and more panels will be the good approach for it or more frames?

Not 'more frames'.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) for the reasons and alternatives.