# What are the types of API versioning?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, web-services

What are the types of  API versioning and How to implement them?

Comment: Your question is only about the Controller? What's it do? ... Also, this is opinion based, so your question is at risk of being closed

Comment: That would be a horrible way to handle versioning. You should have a single code base and version the output accordingly. Have a look at the GSON for versioning.

Comment: This is going to be opinion-based, but I've preferred grouping by version first (among other things, because those tend to be splittable into separate jars or microservices).

Comment: Please, take a look at how HTML is versioned. That is how REST APIs should handle versioning as well as the media-type is the important thing actually. Any proprietary API that does only exchange generic JSON messages bear the danger of tight coupling in it which is what REST actually tries to fix

Comment: what serves me very well is this: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205. The idea is to package not by technical layer, but by business features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, since the question is very board hence this `answer` is by no means the `only` way to achieve `project structure and versioning`. There might be many other ways, I am just sharing what I have previously used as it is relevant.

Apparently there are different ways to structure your codebase namely

- Layer-based project structure
- Feature-based project structure

In `Layer-based project structure` your code is structured based on what different types of layers i.e. controller, service, etc you have whereas in `Feature-based project structure` your code is structured based on `features` of your system, read [here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205) for more info.

There are lots of resources available online that showcase different kind of package structure and I personally stick with `layer-based project structure` because I prefer to organize my codebase based on `layers` rather than features.

## Project structure

One really easy way to get started with a project skeleton, is to look at some example `Spring` webapps. For example, I go to [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) and select the following

- Project name (i.e. myproj)
- Group name (i.e. com)
- Select the modules (i.e. REST, JPA, etc.)
- Generate

Now, I have a REST-based `Spring Boot` project that I can use as a skeleton to customize it as per my `layers`. You do not have to use `Spring Boot` but, what I am trying to showcase is that `Spring Boot` recommended project structure for `REST` web service.

I usually have the following layers

1. controller
2. dao
3. service
4. model
5. dto
6. exception
7. validator
8. util

And so on, here is a screenshot of how the project structure looks like

[image: src/main/java structure]

And the `unit test` package structure would look as follow, you can imagine how the rest of the test classes look like.

[image: src/test/java]

If you have `integration test` or would you refer to it `end to end test` in your java application itself then, you would need

```
src/integ-test/java 
src/integ-test/resources
```

## Endpoint versioning

There might be different ways to version endpoints. One approach that I have previously used is `GSON's versioning support` and it might or might not work for you but, sharing it here anyway. 
If you have noticed in the above screenshot there are the following packages

```
com.myproj.dto.inbound 
com.myproj.dto.outbound
```

`DTO` stands for `Data Transfer Object` and as shown above the `UserInDTO.java` is a representation of `User.java` object that comes in the request and you will be using it with `@RequestBody` in the endpoint in your controller. The `UserOutDTO.java` is a representation of the `User.java` object that goes out. When using DTOs

- You can adopt different naming conventions for what the consumer of the system see and what you use in your model (i.e. `User.java`)
- You can `include` and `exclude` fields in your outgoing and incoming `DTOs` without making unwanted changes to your model/business objects (i.e. `User.java`)

Now that you have DTOs and if you are using `GSON` then you can use it's `Versioning` feature to `include` and `exclude` fields in the `UserOutDTO.java` using annotations such as `@Since(1.5)` and `@Until(2.3)`. Since `GSON` is a serialization/deserialization library or in other words it converts `JSON` to `Java Object` and vice versa, then it has the ability to `include` and `exclude` fields before the `Object` is converted to `JSON` and you can achieve way more with the help of writing serialization and deserialization adapters.

Here is a sample of `UserOutDTO.java` and how the fields are versioned to include and exclude after a certain version

```
public class UserOutDTO {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("User id")
    private int id; 
    @Expose
    private String firstName; 
    @Expose
    private String lastName;

    /*
     * This field will become available for all requests coming for version 2.0 onwards. For a request before 
     * version 2.0 the address field won't be available.
     */
    @Expose
    @Since(2.0)
    private String address; 

    /*
     * This field will become available after version 3.0 an example when you extend your model
     */
    @Expose
    @Until(3.0) 
    private String nickname; 

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

I hope this help. You can also checkout this question, there are a lot of very helpful answers [Package structure for a Java project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210567/package-structure-for-a-java-project)