# are libraries and natives part of resources?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to java and I have been learning things recently that gets me started up like packaging, naming convensions, resources folder and similar stuff the right way.

My question right now is,
I see some people using the libraries/natives folder like this

> Project -> src -> libraries

and as well

> Project -> src -> natives

but some other people do have them in a resource folder like so

> Project -> src -> resources -> libraries

and as well

> Project -> src -> resources -> natives

So I am not sure which one is more correct, but I guess it should be in resources, since they are part of them. Please explain to me.

Comment: See also: [Package structure for a Java project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/210567/5221149)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common convention is the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), core part being:

```
src/main/java        Application/Library sources
src/main/resources   Application/Library resources
```

If you're using Maven, then there is no `libraries` folder, since Maven is responsible for managing the `.jar` files, otherwise `.jar` files and associated native `.dll`/`.so` files are usually put in a `lib` folder *next to* `src`. Alternatively, the native `.dll`/`.so` files are put in a `bin` folder, which contains all files that should be on the PATH.

```
src/main/java        Application/Library Java sources (.java)
src/main/cpp         Application/Library native sources (.cpp)
src/main/resources   Application/Library resources
lib                  Third-Party libraries (.jar)
bin                  Third-Party native files (.dll, .so)
                     and Application/Library scripts (.bat, .sh)
```

Comment: aha interesting, I don't use maven so I should have something like this then
src/libraries and
src/libraries/natives
if I understand correctly.. right?

Comment: @albertos No, you should have `lib` ***next to*** `src`, as in `project/src/main/java`, `project/src/main/resources`, `project/lib`, `project/bin`

Comment: sounds good, here is what I currently have http://prntscr.com/pu1thk

Comment: is it wrong I have natives folder inside libraries? Cause as far as I know they will automatically be generated to the bin folder, and you mentioned ".jar files and associated native .dll/.so files are usually put in a lib folder next to src."