# Cannot find test class in java using JUnit (playerTests.java is not on the classpath of project untitled, it will not be compiled to a .class file)

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm trying to make my test file run some tests, but my project is not recognizing the file as a test file.

This is my playerTests class and on the imports I receive this warning:

> playerTests.java is not on the classpath of project untitled, it will
> not be compiled to a .class file

```java
public class playerTests {

    @Test
    public void testListPlayersByPortalsConquered() {
        
        Player player1 = new Player("Player 1", "Team A", 80, 100, 5);
        Player player2 = new Player("Player 2", "Team B", 90, 100, 3);
        Player player3 = new Player("Player 3", "Team C", 70, 100, 7);
        Player player4 = new Player("Player 4", "Team A", 100, 100, 4);
        Player player5 = new Player("Player 5", "Team B", 60, 100, 2);
        
        player1.setPortalsConquered(10);
        player2.setPortalsConquered(8);
        player3.setPortalsConquered(15);
        player4.setPortalsConquered(12);
        player5.setPortalsConquered(5);
        
        ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
        players.add(player1);
        players.add(player2);
        players.add(player3);
        players.add(player4);
        players.add(player5);
        
        PlayerLoader playerLoader = new PlayerLoader();
        playerLoader.players = players;
        playerLoader.listPlayersByPortalsConquered();
        
        String expectedOutput = "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               | \033[1m\033[31mPlayers ordered by portals\033[0m     |\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               | Player: Player 3\n"
                + "               | Portals Conquered: 15\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               | Player: Player 4\n"
                + "               | Portals Conquered: 12\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               | Player: Player 1\n"
                + "               | Portals Conquered: 10\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               | Player: Player 2\n"
                + "               | Portals Conquered: 8\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n"
                + "               | Player: Player 5\n"
                + "               | Portals Conquered: 5\n"
                + "               ----------------------------------\n";

        String tempFile = "temp.txt";
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
            playerLoader.listPlayersByPortalsConquered();
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            String output = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(tempFile)));
            assertEquals(expectedOutput, output);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is the path of my test class]

[image: Doesn't find the test file]

Comment: Test classes belong to src/test/java in a java test project structure, not the target folder. Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210567/package-structure-for-a-java-project)

Comment: should I create a test/java folder inside src and put there my test class?

Comment: Yes, according to the common convention. Have a look at the link in my comment and also do a little research on project structures in Java.

Comment: thanks @Fuzail it is solved :) Though it was to use the target folder because it created a tests folder by default on generating the project.