# What is the first line for, in the MainActivity.java?

Tags: java, android, package, java-package

`package com.mycompany.myapp2;`

I want to know what this does for my application.

I am a beginner. I'm trying to learn how to develop an android application.
Thank you ❤️.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226282/are-there-best-practices-for-java-package-organization, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125293/java-packages-com-and-org, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210567/package-structure-for-a-java-project, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292169/what-package-naming-convention-do-you-use-for-personal-hobby-projects-in-java, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-package/info

Comment: From Oracle's [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/): see the  [Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html) Trail

Answer (score 1):

The line just inform to Java where you class is located in the project. It is called [package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html), but if you browse your project, in case you are using eclipse or something like, it is just a folder.

Answer (score 1):

A package in Java is used to group related classes. Think of it as a folder in a file directory. We use packages to avoid name conflicts, and to write a better maintainable code.
[more details](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_packages.asp)